# Custom dumper in pyYAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I would like to customise the way a dictionary is dumped to a yaml file.
More precisely, given the following dictionary:

```
{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 '__duplicate__c': [3, 4, 5]}
```

I would like to dump it to a yaml file with keys starting with `__duplicate__` handled as follow:

```
'a': 1
'b': 2
'c': 3
'c': 4
'c': 5
```

I have already written a custom constructor subclassing `yaml.constructor.BaseConstructor` and a custom loader that reads YAML files with duplicate keys, and I would now like to have the possibility to write yaml file with duplicate keys as well.

Comment: The output you show is not valid YAML (YAML forbids duplicate keys). Since you are writing something that isn't a YAML file, a YAML library will probably not help you here.

Comment: That being said, like I mentioned in the question, I was able to subclass a Loader to load these _invalid_ YAML files with duplicate keys. Why not do the opposite as well?

Comment: Because you're basically depending on undefined behavior that may go away in any update of the library. That's asking for maintenance hell.

Comment: @BiBi The main problem is with your representation. You should not assign special meaning to keys formatted, thereby masking their normal use. Instead create a class that works like a dict, that keeps track of the special keys with a set and that has a special method to query if a key has "duplicate" meaning. Then you can just write your (invalid) YAML by creating a normal representer for that class. Loading will need to be done by subclassing the BaseConstructor, as otherwise PyYAML already gobbled the preceding values for `c` (it should give a warning and keep the first value found).

Comment: @Anthon your approach is what I'm trying to implement. I already have subclassed BaseConstructor to handle duplicate keys when loading (invalid) YAML –it doesn't discard duplicate keys but keeps track of them in some structure. That being said, provided I have subclassed dict to handle dulplicate keys, I don't know how to go about dumping this special dict in a YAML file to obtain the expected output (invalid YAML with duplicate keys).

Comment: @BiBi Have you looked at `add_representer` in the PyYAML documentation? (Alternatively you can make the dict like class a subclass of `YAMLObject`). In any event it would be better not output the invalid YAML that you propose, but a valid (and tagged) datastructure. Have you considered that?

Comment: @Anthon what would be a _valid_ datastructure that resemble YAML but can handle duplicate keys?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things not entirely clear, but assuming this is not
just a programming exercise, I took it as that you have data that you read in from somewhere that 
has value pairs, and that you:

- want to look up based on the first value of those pairs
- can have duplicates in the first value
- you need to be able to dump it to YAML and loaded back from YAML

In the following I assume your input data looks like the following Python, but it could
of course also come from some data file, or some other structure that can handle duplicates (Python `dict`s cannot):

```
data = [('a', 1),
        ('b', 2),
        ('c', 3),
        ('c', 4),
        ('c', 5),
]
```

#### Representation in Python

You indicate you store the data in a normal dict with duplicate keys
transformed to `__duplicate__c`, this is not a good choice in general
as it is going to lead to problems.

First of al you cannot add a method to a built-in dict that handles these special
keys, so your code for that will float around your program and/or tests for these
special keys is duplicated.

Second, this makes original data entries of the form:

```
      ('__duplicate__X': 42),
```

impossible to store without extra handling, as would entries like

```
      (4, 1),
      ('4', 2),
      (4, 3),
      ('4', 4),
```

, because, in a generic case, you have to decide how to handle
non-string repeated values, and if you map them those to a string you mask the string versions of
those "keys".

Even if your data is restricted to the first of the data item pairs
being a string it would be better to create a `dict` like class, or
subclass `dict`, that way you can keep a list internally of the
duplicated keys and handle those in a special way cq. require special
access methods.

#### Representation in YAML

The way you propose to dump results in invalid YAML. No other programs can simple load this data. 
In modern YAML (1.2) keys in a mapping must be unique, and that not being the case is an error.
In the now ten years outdated YAML 1.1 specification, of which PyYAML is a partial implementation,
you are allowed to ignore second keys with an appropriate warning. Please note that

It is much more appropriate to dump your data with a tag, e.g.:

```
!MultiDict
- [c]
- a: 1
  b: 2
  c: [3, 4, 5]
```

The above explicitly requires a handler for that tag and loading will
fail if that is not handled.  With your "YAML" representation as input
unmodified PyYAML neither gives a warning error nor loads the correct
value (`3`).

( There is a multidict package on PyPI, but it cannot hanlde non-string keys. )

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object
from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO

yaml = YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = None

data = [('a', 1),
        ('b', 2),
        ('c', 3),
        ('c', 4),
        ('c', 5),
        (4, 1),
        ('4', 2),
        (4, 3),
        ('4', 4),
]

class MultiDictDuplicateKeyError(Exception):
    pass

@yaml_object(yaml)
class MultiDict(dict):
    """ no support for deletion of keys """
    yaml_tag = '!MultiDict'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.__duplicate__ = []
        if args and not isinstance(args[0], dict):
            dict.__init__(self, **kw)
            for arg in args[0]:
                self[arg[0]] = arg[1]
        else:
            dict.__init__(self, *args, **kw)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            if key in self.__duplicate__:  # it should already be a list
                dict.__getitem__(self, key).append(value)
            else:
                self.__duplicate__.append(key)
                dict.__setitem__(self, key, [dict.__getitem__(self, key), value])
        else:
             dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.__duplicate__:
            raise MultiDictDuplicateKeyError("should use multival(key)")
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

    def multival(self, key):
        assert key in self.__duplicate__
        values = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        assert isinstance(values, list)
        for value in values:
             yield value

    def __str__(self):
        return repr({('__duplicate__' + repr(k) if k in self.__duplicate__ else k): v 
                    for k, v in self.items()})

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_sequence(cls.yaml_tag, [node.__duplicate__, dict(node)])

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        # necessary to deal with recursive data structures
        for y in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node.value[1]):
            pass
        for dup in constructor.construct_yaml_seq(node.value[0]):
            pass
        ret = cls(y)
        ret.__duplicate__ = dup
        return ret

md = MultiDict(data)

print('md', md)
print('='*40)
for k in md:
    try:
        print(repr(k), '->', md[k])
    except MultiDictDuplicateKeyError:
        for v in md.multival(k):
            print(repr(k), '->', v)
print('='*40)
yaml.dump(md, sys.stdout)           
print('='*40)

buf = StringIO()
yaml.dump(md, buf)
rt_data = yaml.load(buf.getvalue())
print('rt:', rt_data)
```

which gives:

```
md {'a': 1, 'b': 2, "__duplicate__'c'": [3, 4, 5], '__duplicate__4': [1, 3], "__duplicate__'4'": [2, 4]}
========================================
'a' -> 1
'b' -> 2
'c' -> 3
'c' -> 4
'c' -> 5
4 -> 1
4 -> 3
'4' -> 2
'4' -> 4
========================================
!MultiDict
- [c, 4, '4']
- a: 1
  b: 2
  c: [3, 4, 5]
  4: [1, 3]
  '4': [2, 4]
========================================
rt: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, "__duplicate__'c'": [3, 4, 5], '__duplicate__4': [1, 3], "__duplicate__'4'": [2, 4]}
```

I am using `ruamel.yaml` here (disclaimer I am the author of that package), but
with some adjustments (using `add_representer` and `add_constructor`) the same result
should be achievable by using PyYAML, without subclassing the `BaseConstructor`.